# Why does my string not parse properly in my linq to objects query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

The `CreateDate`(a field in my table used to store the date a record was created) is stored as an nvarchar in my table. In my linq to objects I am trying to parse that same `CreateDate` to a DateTime instead of a string. To accomplish this I tried:

```
var CompYear1 = (from p in C1Result where
DateTime.ParseExact(p.CreateDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", null) >= Y1StartDate 
//throws following error
```

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Here is an example of `CreateDate`

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `p` which results in the error?

Comment: the value of p is the table name to be referenced in sql server. For example table.column

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct format for the dates in `p.CreateDate`?  Can you show example values that fail?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `p.CreateDate`.  What is the value of `p.CreateDate` when the error is thrown?

Comment: @juharr perhaps my post was confusing. The line that throws the error is `DateTime.ParseExact(p.CreateDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null) >= Y1StartDate`

Comment: `"10/13/2014  3:31 PM"` is not in the format `"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`.  `ParseExact` really does mean *exact*.

Comment: @David nailed it. the format should be "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt".  That said, if you have any influence at all I would strongly urge you to try and change the DB type from varchar to datetime.

Comment: I changed my code using your suggestions and I still get the same error

Comment: Is this Linq query applied on your DB object or any generic collection? I have seen errors when you try to manipulate data in linq query[On entity framework] as it uses differed execution.

Comment: @Skullomania You have to use `"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"` to match single digit hour without leading zero.

Comment: @airafr I have tried this as well

Comment: Does it fail on the same input or a different input? Do other rows have leading zeros on the month and/or day?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("10/12/2013 3:31 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```